# Postgres not very fast at finding unique values in table with about 1.3 billion rows

Tags: postgresql, performance, indexing, unique

So I have a (logged) table with two columns A, B, containing text.
They basically contain the same type of information, it's just two columns because of where the data came from.

I wanted to have a table of all unique values (so I made the column be the primary key), not caring about the column. But when I asked postgres to do

insert into new_table(value) select A from old_table on conflict (value) do nothing; (and later on same thing for column B)

it used 1 cpu core, and only read from my SSD with about 5 MB/s. I stopped it after a couple of hours.

I suspected that it might be because of the b-tree being slow and so I added a hashindex on the only attribute in my new table. But it's still using 1 core to the max and reading from the ssd at only 5 MB/s per second. My java program can hashset that at at least 150 MB/s, so postgres should be way faster than 5 MB/s, right? I've analyzed my old table and I made my new table unlogged for faster inserts and yet it still uses 1 core and reads extremely slowly.

How to fix this?

EDIT: This is the explain to the above query. Seems like postgres is using the b-tree it created for the primary key instead of my (much faster, isn't it??) Hash index.

```
Insert on users  (cost=0.00..28648717.24 rows=1340108416 width=14)
  Conflict Resolution: NOTHING
  Conflict Arbiter Indexes: users_pkey
  ->  Seq Scan on games  (cost=0.00..28648717.24 rows=1340108416 width=14)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ON CONFLICT` mechanism is primarily for resolving concurrency-induced conflicts.  You can use it in a "static" case like this, but other methods will be more efficient.

Just insert only distinct values in the first place:

```
insert into new_table(value) 
    select A from old_table union
    select B from old_table
```

For increased performance, don't add the primary key until after the table is populated.  And set work_mem to the largest value you credibly can.

> My java program can hashset that at at least 150 MB/s,

That is working with the hashset entirely in memory.  PostgreSQL indexes are disk-based structures.  They do benefit from caching, but that only goes so far and depends on hardware and settings you haven't told us about.

> Seems like postgres is using the b-tree it created for the primary key instead of my (much faster, isn't it??) Hash index.

It can only use the index which defines the constraint, which is the btree index, as hash indexes cannot support primary key constraints.  You could define an EXCLUDE constraint using the hash index, but that would just make it slower yet.  And in general, hash indexes are *not* "much faster" than btree indexes in PostgreSQL.

Comment: i7-8750H 6 cores 2.2 Ghz base hyperthreading, 16 GB RAM 2666, SSD with 3 GB read write during benchmark, lots of free space, GPU doesn't matter I suppose?

Comment: Right, GPU doesn't matter.  Core count doesn't either, as parallel query currently doesn't support INSERT statements.  How many rows does the result set have?  16GB is probably not enough to hash them all, unless the input is mostly duplicates.

Comment: The result set had a little more than 1.083.000.000